# Fail2Ban regex for EXIM (TCP/IP connection count)

Tags: regex, exim, fail2ban

I am trying to create a regex condition for the exim filter of Fail2Ban. In my exim log, I have entries like this:

2014-11-27 17:09:05 SMTP connection from [42.117.255.244] (TCP/IP connection count = 1)

2014-11-27 17:09:14 SMTP connection from [118.68.249.18] (TCP/IP connection count = 2)

2014-11-27 17:09:15 SMTP connection from [113.188.85.220] (TCP/IP connection count = 3)

So I need a regex filter which analyzes the exim log, and if TCP/IP connection count > 3, then fail2ban will block that ip for the amount of time specified in fail2ban configuration.

What I have tried so far is something like this:

failregex =  ^%(pid)s SMTP connection from \S+ [](:\d+)? (I=[\S+]:\d+ )?(TCP/IP connection count = "\S+")\s*$

but it fails ... I am not any good at regex so I need your help.

Thank you!

Comment: Anyone? Any  ideeas? I really don't get it why is not working although on that regex101.com website, the regex expression seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ \S]+?SMTP connection from \S+? \(TCP\/IP connection count = (?!\b1\b|\b2\b|\b3\b)\d+\)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/10

Comment: thank you but is not working! Here is what I get: 

root@zira in /etc/fail2ban (8 entries, 0 hidden)
88/25083# fail2ban-regex /var/log/exim_mainlog "SMTP connection from \S+? \(TCP\/IP connection count = (?!\b1\b|\b2\b|\b3\b)\d+\)"

-bash: !\b1\b: event not found


root@zira in /etc/fail2ban (8 entries, 0 hidden)

Comment: Does your `fail2ban` support lookaheads?

Comment: although on that site the regex works perfectly, it doesn't work. I even have tried to simply it like this:

SMTP connection from \S+? \(TCP\/IP connection count = 

just to try to detect all the connections but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I don't know if it supports lookaheads.. How do I check that?

Comment: Fail2ban is written in python so basically the regex should work but it doesn't

Comment: 104/25098# fail2ban-regex /var/log/exim_mainlog "\[<HOST>\] +?SMTP connection from \S+? \(TCP\/IP connection count = \d+\) /gmi"

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : \[<HOST>\] +?SMTP connection from \S+? \(TCP\/IP c...
Use         log file : /var/log/exim_mainlog


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [3002] Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 3002 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 3002 missed
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 3002 lines

Still not working!

Comment: Yeah well, probably fail2ban uses a different regex or something like that. for example:

\[<HOST>\] .*(?:relay not permitted) in file exim-relay.conf is working fine with fail2ban, but if I try to use that in that regex demo is not working... So something is clearly wrong... thank you for everything anyway, I will keep digging